# MVC architecture like BAL, DAL and Presentation with EntityFramework?

Tags: c#-4.0, model-view-controller, entity-framework-4

I want to create a project in Asp.Net MVC with C# using Entity Framework with BAL and DAL layers ? There are two module here User and Admin module with custom login feature. Admin can add run time columns in the existing database with add, edit update the records such as any report.
The record display to the users.

If you have any such type of reference article/project (N-tier architecture) let us know please.

Answer (score 1):

When i create MVC projects, i usually follow this structure:

- UI Layer - This will be the actual mvc project and will interact with the service layer
- Service Layer (BAL) - This will hold all your business logic classes and will interact with the data access layer. This layer will expose services the UI Layer can make use of
- Data Access Layer - This will hold all classes related to data access. As you are using entity framework, your DbContext can live here
- Entities - This will hold all entities used in your solution